# How to create 10bit YUY2 packed YUV Renderer?

Tags: linux, windows, sdl, render, sdl-2

I have created 8 bit yuv player for format YUY2 packed using SDL lib,some part of code:

```
handle->texture = SDL_CreateTexture(handle->renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YUY2, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);

SDL_UpdateTexture(handle->texture, NULL,pDisplay->Ydata,(handle->width*2));
```

in that while creating texture,pixel format is given `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YUY2` and update texture pitch in twice of width. So it is playing fine.

But when it comes to 10 bit YUV, it plays disturbed and greenish video.

What I have tried is changed pitch to `(handle->width*2 * 2)` but no success
also someone suggested to convert 10bit value to 8bit but I don't want to do that.

Please help me to play 10bit YUY2 packed format YUV.
Is SDL support more than 8 bit depth pixel rendering ?

Comment: Hi there, your codec needs to support the pixel format.  If I was to ask my mp3 player to play 8 or 16 bit/saple it will be able to do so.  If I was to ask it to play 19 bits per sample it won't be able to unless it specifically contains a 19 bit per sample decoder.  Verify that the pixel format you need is supported by the SDL system.

Comment: Decoder is capable to give output of 10bit .....but may be SDL is not supporting 10bit YUY2 ......raw data. So i am here for an alternative.